# How do GAN's generator actually work?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, generative-model, minimax

I have implemented DCGAN's myself and have been studying GAN's for over a month now. Now I am implementing the pggans but I encountered a sentence

> When we measure the distance between
>   the training distribution and the generated distribution, the gradients can point to more or less random
>   directions if the distributions do not have substantial overlap  (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10196.pdf)

but we do never compare the distribution between training and generated distributions in gans a far I know when we train the gan

```
fixed_noise = to.randn(num_test_samples, 100).view(-1,100, 1, 1)
for epoch in range(opt.number_epochs):
D_losses = []
G_losses = []
for i,(images, labels) in enumerate(dataloader):
    minibatch = images.size()[0]
    real_images = Variable(images.cuda()) 
    real_labels = Variable(to.ones(minibatch).cuda())
    fake_labels = Variable(to.zeros(minibatch).cuda())
    ##Train discriminator
    #First with real data 
    D_real_Decision = discriminator(real_images).squeeze()   
    D_real_loss = criterion(D_real_Decision,real_labels)        
    #with fake data        
    z_ = to.randn(minibatch,100 ).view(-1, 100, 1, 1)
    z_ = Variable(z_.cuda())
    gen_images = generator(z_)        
    D_fake_decision = discriminator(gen_images).squeeze()
    D_fake_loss = criterion(D_fake_decision,fake_labels)

    ## back propagation

    D_loss = D_real_loss + D_fake_loss
    discriminator.zero_grad()
    D_loss.backward()
    opt_Disc.step()

    # train generator
    z_ = to.randn(minibatch,100 ).view(-1, 100, 1, 1)
    z_ = Variable(z_.cuda())
    gen_images = generator(z_)

    D_fake_decisions = discriminator(gen_images).squeeze()
    G_loss = criterion(D_fake_decisions,real_labels)

    discriminator.zero_grad()
    generator.zero_grad()
    G_loss.backward()
    opt_Gen.step()
```

we just train the discriminator on real and fake images, and then train generator on the outputs of discriminator on generated images,

**So Please let me know where do we compare the distribution between training and generated distribution, and how do generator learns to mimic the training samples**